# Como apagar um termo inserido um formulário usando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

O código abaixo faz parte de uma função que usa um termo de busca em um campo de texto para extrair imagens do site Flickr. Após digitar a palavra para fazer a busca, ele insere o texto abaixo do campo, apenas para mostrar que está procurando aquilo, mas o problema é que sempre que digito um novo termo, ele insere o novo termo na página, ao invés de zerar as imagens e o termo.

```
var $tag,
    $status,
    $msg;

    if ($("main .container .busca input").val() !== "") {
        $status = $("<p>").text($("main .container .busca input").val());
        $tag = $("main .container .busca input").val();
        $msg = ("<p> Encontramos essas imagens para você:</p>");
        $("main .container .busca").append($msg).append($status);
        $("main .container .busca input").val("");
    };
```

[image: Buscando fotos]

Gostaria que toda vez que eu digitasse um novo termo, ele apagasse o anterior, bem como as imagens, e inserisse o novo termo embaixo da caixa de texto. Alguém poderia me dar uma pista de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
var $tag,
$status,$msg;

if ($("main .container .busca input").val() !== "") {
    $("main .container .busca p").text("");
    $status = ("<p>" + $(".busca input").val() + "</p>");
    $tag = $("main .container .busca input").val();
    $msg = ("<p> Encontramos essas imagens para você:</p>");
    $("main .container .busca").append($msg).append($status);
    $("main .container .busca input").val("");
};
```

ou isso, dependendo seu código HTML:

```
var $tag,
$status,$msg;

if ($("main .container .busca input").val() !== "") {
    $("main .container .busca p").remove();
    $status = ("<p>" + $("main .container .busca input").val() + "</p>");
    $tag = $("main .container .busca input").val();
    $msg = ("<p> Encontramos essas imagens para você:</p>");
    $("main .container .busca").append($msg).append($status);
    $("main .container .busca input").val("");
};
```

Comment: A primeira solução que você apresentou já resolveu, ajustei ela inclusive para que fizesse o mesmo com as imagens. Muito obrigada! ^_^